# Embed Cython and VLC Python bindings

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, cython, libvlc

I have some python project with PySide GUI. I'm also using python bindings for [libvlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings). I know about pyinstaller etc. but I need to compile project to a standalone exe for Windows using [cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython).

The result always crashes for some unknown reason, but without vlc.py all is ok. What are the problems, maybe they are not compatible? Is it possible to a make standalone exe using cython and vlc bindings?

Comment: Can you provide the commands you used to create the standalone app? Please include all options.